# Why do my two cloud servers act diffrently on dht crawler?

Tags: java, linux, cloud, bittorrent, dht

I wrote a dht torrents crawler by java based on `Bittorrent Protocol`. It works well on a 1c2g1m cloud server `A` from which I got some torrents.

Then I bought another cloud server `B` which is called `Lighthouse`. `B` is 1c2g5m and limits 1000g. But my crawler didn't work on `B` from which I cannot get any response e.g. `find_node` responses.

I tested `B` using linux `nc` for udp sending and receiving. There's no problem. I also used the two servers sending and receiving udp packets each other. No problem too.

Another strange thing is that I received some `sample_infohashes` request defined in [bep_0051](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0051.html) on `B` and the ip is 127.0.0.1:43928, hahaha ... I used `router.bittorrent.com, 6881` for initialization. So I think the `sample_infohashes` messages were from `router.bittorrent.com`.

Why do my two cloud servers act so diffrently?

Comment: Perhaps your server B has no IPv4 connectivity? Or is behind a firewall or NAT? You could try to send a DHT ping from A to B.

Comment: Oh, I know you, super star! I followed you on github
I've tried to send ping as I said above. 
 > I also used the two servers sending and receiving udp packets each other. No problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't provide sufficient information to pinpoint the cause. Between your bittorrent crawler and the network interface of the server are many abstraction layers where things can go wrong.

The crawler might be binding to the wrong interface. DHT packets might be malformed and get ignored by remote peers. You might be parsing responses incorrectly. There could be a firewall in place silently dropping things, either on the server or in the cloud provider infrastructure. The host could have bad routing where parts of the internet aren't reachable.  Many possible reasons.

You'll simply have to try various network diagnostic tools such as `tcpdump`/`wireshark`, `ss`, `nstat`, `traceroute` etc. and gather more data to learn what's actually happening. Since your question is also tagged as java: Make sure to that helpful exception messages don't get silenced.

Since you have a host that's working and one that isn't working it should make things a lot easier since you can compare results.

You also might want to test sending messages between different clients, in case one of them is buggy.

Comment: The two servers use the same jar, so remote peers should not ignore and my parsing for responses are certainly right. The two servers can send DHT "ping" to the other and receive the "ping" response from the other, so I don't think firewall or some other things go wrong.

Comment: Now the crawler works fine. I think it's the server network problem. I did not change anything.